# How to use Perks?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

In Call of Duty: Black Ops for the Nintendo DS, I have some perks that I have unlocked for online play. But the problem is, I don't know how to use them! Can someone explain to me how to use perks?

Comment: which perks are you talking about? Normally you can just select them in your "Create a class"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add perks for custom classes.  To create a custom class, click the "CREATE A CLASS" option on the main screen in multiplayer.  Your available perks can be selected in the perks section when creating a class.

To use the perks, you must select the class during a game.  More class slots can be unlocked as you prestige to higher levels.

Comment: Is this referring to the DS version?